# Oracle SQL Case Statement Subquery returns more than one row Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple case statement where I'm trying to get a list of values depending on the user role:

```
select distinct
case
    when user_email in (select users from my_table_1 where user_type = 'A')
    then (select distinct type_products from my_total_table where products = 'A')
else null
end
from my_total_table
```

This is throwing me a single subquery returns more than one row error.

```
My_total_table structure:
type_products     Name
A                 Something1
A                 Something2
A                 Something3
B                 ProductB1
B                 ProductB2
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
Desired result would be:
If user is on my_table_1 and the person is a type A, then I want to call all Products from my_total_table that belong to the A category and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Tables structure, sample data and desired output are highly welcome

Comment: `select distinct type_products from my_total_table where products = 'A'` This is going to return more than one row, right? That is where your issue is.

Comment: Perhaps you should LEFT JOIN the subquery instead?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data (both tables and desired result) would help; meanwhile, see if one (or both?) of these helps:

```
select distinct type_products
from my_total_table
where products = 'A'
  and user_email in (select users 
                     from my_table_1
                     where user_type = 'A'
                    );
                    
select distinct a.type_products
from my_total_table a join my_table_1 b on a.user_email = b.users
where b.user_type = 'A'
  and a.products = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, but it looks like your data is something like here:

```sql
WITH
  tbl_users (USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_TYPE) AS
    (
        Select 1, 'User_1', 'user1@some.com', 'A' From Dual Union All
        Select 2, 'User_2', 'user2@some.com', 'B' From Dual Union All
        Select 3, 'User_3', 'user3@some.com', 'A' From Dual 
    ),
    tbl_total (TYPE_PRODUCTS, TOTAL_NAME) AS
        (
        Select 'A',     'Something_1'   From Dual   Union All
        Select 'A',     'Something_2'   From Dual   Union All
        Select 'A',     'Something_3'   From Dual   Union All
        Select 'B',     'ProductB_1'      From Dual     Union All
        Select 'B',     'ProductB_2'      From Dual     
        ),
```

If so, you could create a cte to join the data that could be selectable in different ways:

```sql
  cte_types AS
    (
        Select      tu.USER_ID, tu.USER_NAME, tu.USER_EMAIL, tu.USER_TYPE,
                    tt.TOTAL_NAME
        From        tbl_users tu
        Inner Join  tbl_total tt ON(tt.TYPE_PRODUCTS = tu.USER_TYPE)
        Order By    tu.USER_ID, tt.TOTAL_NAME 
        )

cte_types resulting dataset:
   USER_ID USER_NAME USER_EMAIL     USER_TYPE TOTAL_NAME 
---------- --------- -------------- --------- -----------
         1 User_1    user1@some.com A         Something_1
         1 User_1    user1@some.com A         Something_2
         1 User_1    user1@some.com A         Something_3
         2 User_2    user2@some.com B         ProductB_1 
         2 User_2    user2@some.com B         ProductB_2 
         3 User_3    user3@some.com A         Something_1
         3 User_3    user3@some.com A         Something_2
         3 User_3    user3@some.com A         Something_3
```

Using the cte as a source - select whatever you want:

```sql
Select  DISTINCT USER_TYPE, TOTAL_NAME 
From    cte_types
Where   USER_TYPE = 'A'
Order By TOTAL_NAME

USER_TYPE TOTAL_NAME 
--------- -----------
A         Something_1
A         Something_2
A         Something_3
```